# How to configure Realm Object Server v2.0.4 for HTTPS connections?

Tags: https, configuration, realm-object-server

I have deployed Realm Object Server v2.0.4 onto Ubuntu and also implemented LetsEncrypt.  I can connect using the new Realm Studio - all seems good.

Now that the base server is in place I need to configure it to use HTTPS and disable HTTP - and this is where I'm struggling.

I have created a new Realm project using `ros init bb` (bb is just a temp project name) and the folder structure looks like this:

```
bb
└───src
│   │   index.ts
```

I have updated `index.ts` to contain the following:

```
import { BasicServer } from 'realm-object-server'
import * as path from 'path'

const BasicServer = require('realm-object-server').BasicServer
const path = require('path')
const server = new BasicServer()

server.start({
        console.log(`Does this get logged?`),
        dataPath: path.join(__dirname, '../data'),
        https-enable: true,
        https-key: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/{my domain in here}/privkey.pem',
        https-cert: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/{my domain in here}/cert.pem',
        https-address: 0.0.0.0,
        https-port: 9443
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Your server is started `, server.address)
    })    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Your server is started `, server.address)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`There was an error starting your file`)
    })
```

When I start ros (`ros start`) the console outputs:

```
info: Realm Object Server version 2.0.4 is starting
info: Realm sync server started ([realm-core-4.0.2], [realm-sync-2.0.2]) service=sync
info: Directory holding persistent state: /home/ros_admin/bb/data/sync/user_data service=sync
info: Operating mode: master_with_no_slave service=sync
info: Listening on 127.0.0.1:36580 (sync protocol version 22) service=sync
info: sync-client: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '127.0.0.1:36580' (from '127.0.0.1:55292')
info: sync-client: Connection[2]: Connected to endpoint '127.0.0.1:36580' (from '127.0.0.1:55294')
info: sync-client: Connection[3]: Connected to endpoint '127.0.0.1:36580' (from '127.0.0.1:55296')
info: Starting auth provider 'password'
info: sync-client: Connection[4]: Connected to endpoint '127.0.0.1:36580' (from '127.0.0.1:55298')
info: 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__admin HTTP/1.1 200 41 - 6.342 ms
info: 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__revocation HTTP/1.1 200 46 - 1.071 ms
info: 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__wildcardpermissions HTTP/1.1 200 55 - 1.201 ms
info: 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__password HTTP/1.1 200 44 - 0.629 ms
info: Realm Object Server has started and is listening on http://0.0.0.0:9080
info: sync-client: Connection[5]: Connected to endpoint '0.0.0.0:9080' (from '127.0.0.1:33262')
info: sync-client: Connection[6]: Connected to endpoint '0.0.0.0:9080' (from '127.0.0.1:33266')
```

Because I'm not seeing any of the console log output I have to assume my configuration is not being called.  Which leads me to think that I've placed the configuration in the wrong file or location or that there is an extra step that I'm missing.

Can anyone advise?  Or does anyone have an example configuration they can share?

Comment: An update.  If I launch ROS using command line switches, HTTPS successfully starts.  ```ros start --https --https-key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{my domain in here}/privkey.pem --https-cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/{my domain in here}/cert.pem```  The log output shows `info: Realm Object Server has started and is listening on http://0.0.0.0:9080 and https://0.0.0.0:9443`

Answer (score 0):

Your config object is malformed. It should be a valid JSON value.

1. The first `console.log()` line is invalid JSON
2. The key names you have provided which have hyphens and are unquoted are invalid
3. The IP value needs to be quoted as a string

The command line flag names are different than their javascript equivalent in the config object you pass to `server.start()`.

```js
server.start({
        dataPath: path.join(__dirname, '../data'),
        https: true,
        httpsKeyPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/{my domain in here}/privkey.pem',
        httpsCertChainPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/{my domain in here}/cert.pem',
        httpsAddress: '0.0.0.0',
        httpsPort: 9443
    })
```

See the [example Typescript or Javascript config here for more information](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/latest#init-ts-ros).